# In MVVM, who creates the views, view models, and models? And who connects them together?

Tags: mvvm

In MVVM,

1. Who creates the first and subsequent views, view models, and models?
2. Who displays the views?
3. And who decides which views and which models connect to which view model?

It feels to me like there is always going to be some code/XML/configuration/etc. -- some "connecting tissue", so to speak -- that doesn't fit into any of the Model, View Model, or Model components.

Comment: MVVM frameworks are there to "connect-the-dots" so to speak. I'd look into a few of those - building all that boilerplate yourself can be time-consuming.

Comment: 1) is two questions.  The first view is constructed by running the executable, subsequent are controlled by your code 2) your code 3) your code.  Why not sit down and write a small prototype that does something simple and see how the pieces fit.

Comment: @Will You say "your code". The question is, which part of my code. The view, the view model, or model?

Comment: Anyone have a WPF version answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MVVM` is a pattern for decoupling UI from code. It's not for building entire application only with these 3 types of classes (view,viewmodel,model). You can still have factories, bootstrappers, repositories, etc.

1. First view is created differently depending on framework. For
   example in `Caliburn.Micro` first view is created in class
   `Bootstrapper` with `DisplayViewFor<MainViewModel>`
2. There is usually a build-in class that is responsible for looking
   into folder with specific name (Views) that extracts `Views` and
   matches them with `ViewModels`.
3. Views and models are connected by name. You have to follow a certain
   naming convention: `Class1View` is connected to `Class1ViewModel`.
   Models are usually passed via constructor.

Note that I base my knowledge mostly on how `Caliburn.Micro` does it, but I suspect that it isn't very different from what other frameworks do.

Comment: CM is a good example, but it's very convention heavy by default - I wouldn't be surprised if other MVVM frameworks are more explicit about the way they match views/viewmodels - not to mention that you can use the same viewmodel for many views. I'd say that it will depend heavily on framework - each one does things differently.

Comment: In `Caliburn.Micro` you can even change the way that views are matched with viewModels, so yes you are right, it very heavily depends on framework. It's hard to give a precise response to such a broad question.